# My own random number generator

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

I want to make a random number generator where the user specifies the range and amount of generated numbers. I want it to make every number unique (no repeat). This is what I've done so far (it generates but some of them repeat, why?)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int start, stop, amount;

    system("chcp 1250 >nul");

    printf("Welcome to random number generator!\n");
    printf("\nWhat range? \nFrom: "); scanf("%i", &start);
    printf("To: "); scanf("%i", &stop);

    printf("\nHow many numbers?: "); scanf("%i", &amount);
    int number[amount];

    for(int i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        number[i] = rand() % ((stop+1)-start) + start;

            for(int j=i; j>-1; j--)
            {
                if(number[i]==number[j])
                {
                    number[i] = rand() % ((stop+1)-start) + start;
                }
            }

        printf("\n%i generated number: %i", i+1, number[i]);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::set`, insert into the set until you have `amount` numbers in it. Also, use `<random>` instead of `rand()`

Comment: Hmm. I think if the OP is using printf/scanf `std::set` most likely was not covered yet..

Comment: OK, but can you tell me why doesn't my code work? Teoritycally it should do it.

Comment: @user3478487 You aren't checking that the second assignment is not also a duplicate.  If you generate a new number you have to reset `j` to `i-1` after reassigning `number[i]`.  Also, as it stands you always do one re-assignment since you are comparing `number[i] == number[j]` when `i` and `j` are equal, `j` should be initialized to `i-1`.

Comment: What if the number is larger than the interval (edit: sorry, also mentioned by Marc B.)? Also note that you're relying on a compiler extension when you do `int number[amount]`.

Answer (score 3):

Your "check for dupes" loop is incorrect. You might find a duplicate, but then you don't check if that re-generated number exists in the stuff you ALREADY tested.

e.g. consider an array like this. user asked for 5 numbers, range 1-10

```
number[0] = 5
number[1] = 6
number[2] = 2
number[3] = 8
```

Now you're working on number[4]. You generate `2`... You scan the array backwards and find that `2` is a dupe. So you generate a new number... and generate `8`. But you don't reset your `j` loop  - you just keep working backwards, and never see that `8` was already in the array.

What you should have is something more like:

```
        for(int j=i; j>-1; j--) {
            if(number[i]==number[j]) {
                number[i] = rand() % ((stop+1)-start) + start;
                j = i; // RESET THE LOOP
            }
        }
```

And note that your code can easily produce an infinite loop. e.g. consider someone asking for numbers in a range 1-3, and generate 4 of them. `1,2,3,?`. The condition can never be satisfied, because you can't have 1-3 without at least one repeat.

Comment: that's a very suboptimal solution. It will work, but imagine what will happen if you're trying to generate a lot of numbers and you're close to the end. you're generate a dupe most of the time and keep repeating this loop.

Comment: yeah, but OP's not asking for an efficient solution.

Comment: I just want him to be aware of this. This may be an issue especially with real life random number generators that aren't really uniform. It will use up all the frequent values at the very beginning and then may end up stuck trying to find the remaining numbers

Comment: you need to change j = i to j = i - 1 or this loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

So, even if we assume that rand() is a perfect random number generator, the numbers would repeat.
Lets say you have to generate 100 numbers. Say your start = 1 and stop = 100.

you generate a first number from 1 to 100, then the second and so on.. The more numbers you've used so far, the easier it is to get a duplicate.

Then you find a duplicate with that inner for-loop. You generate a new number for
number[i], but you have no guarantee that this number's unique. You may as well end up
setting number[i] to another duplicate.

If you want your code to work, you have to keep changing number[i] as long as it has a duplicate.

That's regarding the bug in your code. 
On the other hand, this code is horribly inefficient, so you should consider optimising it if you plan on running this procedure often.